# Why is TypeTag of T Nothing when I don't explicitly specify type?

Tags: scala, generics

I have a function which prints the type of parameter T. When it's invoked with `foo`, it prints `Int`. When it's invoked with `bar`, it prints `Nothing`. Why does it print `Nothing` when the compiler has clearly figured out that `T` needs to be an `Int` because we're returning the result of `printType()` and the return type of `bar` needs to be an `Int`?

The code compiles and runs, but the type is printed incorrectly.

```
def printType[T](input: String)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): Option[T] = {
  val t = typeOf[T]
  println(s"$t")
  ...
}

def foo: Int = {
  printType[Int]("something") // prints Int
}

def bar: Int = {
  printType("something")  // prints Nothing
}
```

Comment: Doesn't compile. How does `foo` receive an `Int` if `printType()` returns an `Option[T]`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant

```
def printType[T](input: String)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): T = ...
```

instead of

```
def printType[T](input: String)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): Option[T] = ...
```

If you have a method

```
def myMethod(a: A): B = ???
```

and you use it

```
val a: A1 = ???
val b: B1 = myMethod(a)
```

then it's not necessary that `A1 = A`, `B1 = B`, it can be `A1 <: A`, `B1 >: B`.

So for

```
def bar: Int = {
  printType("something") 
}
```

it's possible that `printType` returns `Nothing`.

And when compiler fails to infer some type `T`, knowing that `L <: T <: U` it concludes that `T = L`. Now it's `Nothing`.